# Getting obj.map to change all values

Tags: javascript

My vm.countryList list array looks like this:

```
var vm = {
    countryList: [{
        id: "gb",
        name: "Great Britain",
        ticked: true
    }, {
        id: "us",
        name: "United States",
        ticked: true
    }]
};
```

What I want is to set all ticked values to false. 
Can I do that with a map?

```
vm.countryList = vm.countryList.map(ticked=false);
```

This one does not work, but it it possible or do I need a foreach or for (i=...)

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Joey what more do you need?   All I want is to set all ticked values to false in the array.

Comment: you want to update the existing array or you want a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!` operator to toggle `Boolean` `true` to `false`

```js
const obj = [{ id:"gb", name:"Great Britain", ticked:true }
            ,{ id:"us", name:"United States", ticked:true }];

let res = obj.map(o => (o.ticked = !o.ticked, o));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: That one I knew :-)  But in this case I just wanted them all to be false.   (and in other cases change other values with other stuff)  Albertos solution worked great even thou yours is more simple

Comment: @torbenrudgaard _"and in other cases change other values with other stuff"_ does not appear at original Question. Use whichever approach which meets requirement

Comment: would this work?   `vm.currencyList = vm.currencyList.map(o => (o.ticked = false, o));`

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Yes.

Comment: Yep - it worked - just tested it om several cases.  So I have to give the answer to you because this was a lot more simple than the others... and I love simple :)   Thanks guests for this really easy way of doing it :)

Comment: Wow, I did't know you could do that. How does this evaluate to an object: (o.ticked = !o.ticked, o)? @guest271314

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares Note the comma operator `,` within the expression. The portion to the furthest right is returned from the function

Comment: Oh, now I see how that worked. The assignment is performed and the object is returned in that way. Clever!

Comment: The only caveat is that it mutates the original array. Which might be a problem or not, depending on the "functional needs" OP has

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares Good point. In which case OP could utilize the approach at your Answer. From description and code at Question, OP is trying to change values at original array _"My vm.countryList list array looks like this:"_ _"`vm.countryList = vm.countryList.map(ticked=false);`"_

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `map` and still being one-liner with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
vm.countryList = vm.countryList.map((country) => Object.assign({}, country, { ticked: false }));
```

One observation is that you need to pass a function to `map` (that is applied to every item in an array, generating a new array), that's why your code is invalid.

Comment: Alberto that worked perfectly!!  Let me see if I unserstand.  You assign the current `countryList` object to `country` and then you... ehh..  ok I understand where you set the value in the end, but `assign({}, country,` - this part I dont get

Comment: First of all, you need to understand the map. In the map, you iterate the list, and for each iteration, we assign the current item to `country`. The `Object.assign` is to get `country` and "merge" this with `{ ticket: true}`, with the common properties (in this case, only `ticket`) being overridden by the latter, and the result of this merge is added to the first parameter (an empty object) and returned. It is a way to generate a new version of an object by changing only a property (in this case, ticked)

Comment: Thanks Alberto, very powerful and flexible solution.  Even if it was a bit complex :-D  Thanks!

Comment: Haha, yeah, it is complex, but you get used to it quickly. Object.assign({}, {a: 1, b:1}, {b: 2, c: 3}) returns {a: 1, b: 2, c:3}, for example. We merged here these two objects, and the common property (b, in this example) has the value of the second object. It's indeed a powerful way to create new objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the original objects, there's really no point in using `map()` over `forEach()`, as it would be a side-effect of the `map()` iterations.

You can use the `map()` to create a new array with new objects, with your requested modification to the `ticked` property, instead of mutating the orginal array and objects like this:

```
vm.countryList.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, { ticked: false }))
```

Comment: How is your current Answer different from this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133016/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 It's not. Did it not occur to you that maybe, just maybe, I didn't see that answer when I posted mine because that one was posted while I was busy writing mine?

Comment: Yes. That is a possibility. The same circumstance has occurred here as well. The comment was not an accusation, but rather a question.

Answer (score 1):

But I can see that you are overriding the current array with

```
vm.countryList = vm.countryList.map(ticked=false);
```

so isn't it better to update the current array instead creating aa new and assiging it to the same to override? so its much easier and faster to do it:

```
vm.countryList.forEach(country=>country.ticked=false)
```

Comment: also pretty simple and clever Koushik!!  Thanks!